# Heat map of 4x1000 data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have 1000 x 4  data having float values between [0, 100]. How can I create comparison heat map for this data in gnuplot?

I have tried the demo version of heatmap example on Gnuplot. However, I could not find my answer from it.

The data looks like this:

[image]

And what I want to show comparison of each columns(sorted) in heatmap.

For example:

[image]

Comment: What is the format of your data file?  Maybe show us the first few lines.

Comment: @Ethan, Thank you for responding, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it you want to treat the columns individually rather than treating the whole thing as a matrix. The following gnuplot commands will do that:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
set bmargin screen 0.1
set key samplen -1
set style fill solid
set palette defined (0 "forest-green", 1 "goldenrod")

plot for [col=1:4] 'data' \
     using (col):0:(0.45):(1.0):col with boxxy \
     lc palette title columnhead(col) at first col, graph -0.05
```

Notes:

- The boxxy style expects column input x:y:delta_x:delta_y [:optional
  color]
- We give it the column number for x, the line number for y, and a constant size width and height. You can adjust the width to reduce the gap between columns.
- The bottom margin is increased to leave room for the labels
- The titles are placed individually under the plot rather than in a key box

You mention sorting but it is not clear exactly what you want.  If the idea is to sort the values within each column prior to plotting, I think that will have to be done by invoking a system command.  On linux this could be done by replacing the first line of the plot command with something like:

```
plot for [col=1:4] sprintf("<sort -n -k %d data",col) \
    etc
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer solves all my problem. Exactly I wanted to treat each columns individually. Also the data are sorted before the plotting. Much appreciated.